# SSO Azure AD integration with on-premise Client and Sever

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have web app developed in React and API in .net core.
I want to add the Azure AD SSO, azure documentation is very confusing and endless loop.
We have op-premise AD as well. But authentication should follow Azure AD.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I assume you wanna to use azure ad to authentic in the frontend. If so, I think you need to use implicit grant flow to make user login, and [this document](https://medium.com/@pavelray/connect-your-react-app-with-azure-ad-using-3ddd39223d27) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tiny-wa. But as per MS documentation implicit is no more recommended. Authorization code flow with PKCE is recommended. My main problem is my client and server both are on-premise. I just want to authenticate them from Azure AD.

Comment: I already tried with [msal-browser 2.x library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react) but i do not understand how overall flow will work. how my backend will verify my identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out. Basically it is configuration using Authorization Code flow with PKCE.

I have included the step wise settings in-case anybody need it. *(Note: Things changes in Azure very frequently)*

Check out the single page application [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview)
[image]

Comment: Hi @Ganesh , Do you have an example of how do the same using .net framework on the backend side ?

Comment: Sure @IvanFontalvo, Please checkout the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the link just has examples on .net core, I looking for .net framework implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the authorization code flow just now and it was ok to login and call API.

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code#test-your-application).

And about the work flow, can this picture help you ?
[image]

And when calling your backend API, you may add the access token to the calling request and decrypt it to get the claim.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i will try this and let you know if it works. 

Comment: I tried, but this didn't helped. Check out new updated diagram in my main question. That is what I want to achieve.